# Drawing a graph of $x\cos(1/x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I have been given a question which asks to draw the graph of $x\cos\left(\frac 1x\right)$ without a calculator. However, I'm unsure as to how to do this. It may involve differentiation as that was the theme of the question sheet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the derivative of $y=x\cos\left(\frac 1x\right)$?

Comment: (sin(1/x))*(1/x) + cos(1/x)

Comment: but I'm unsure how this helps me draw the graph

Comment: All I can think of to help is to pick a couple points whose values you will be able to determine without a calculator, such as $\cos\left(\frac {\pi}4\right)$ (which means that $x=\frac 4{\pi}$), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Think of this function as $$f(x)=x\cos\left(\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\cdot x\right)$$
What this shows you is that both the amplitude ($x$) and frequency ($\frac{1}{2\pi x^2}$) of the wave tends vary with $x$. As $|x|$ gets large, the amplitude goes to infinity but is offset by a frequency that diminishes to zero. But as $|x|\to0$, the frequency blows up to infinity and the amplitude diminishes to zero.

So as $|x|\to 0$, the frequency keeps increasing, but with a smaller and smaller amplitude.

What about when $|x|\to\infty$? What exactly is happening then? We know the amplitude is getting larger and larger and the frequency is getting smaller and smaller. In particular, notice that as $|x|\to\infty$, $\frac{1}{x}\to0$, so $\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\to1$, and so in the long run the function just approaches $g(x)=x$.

For the sake of comparison, think about the graphs of $x\cos x$ and $\frac{1}{x}\cos x$, too.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this in a rather different way from @symplectomorphic’s.

First imagine the graph $y=\cos\frac1x$. Easiest to see what happens as $x\to\infty$: there’s an asymptote of $y=1$. Then imagine what happens as $x\to0$, so that $\frac1x\to\infty$, and you’re taking the cosine of that: it wiggles, more and more violently as $x\to0$, but always between the bounds $y=\pm\,1$.

You must understand the infinite wiggling as $x\to0$, otherwise you can not go to the next step.

And the next step is just to fit it all between the lines $y=\pm x$.

Now you see it: as $x\to+\infty$, the function value gets closer and closer to the line $y=x$, and as $x\to0$, there are infinitely many wiggles, but getting smaller and smaller.